# const keyword and duplicate method signature

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++, switching from a JAVA environment.

When reading through some Boost examples I found the following two methods defined in a class:

```
const char* data() const
{
    return data_;
}

char* data()
{
  return data_;
}
```

There are two things that confuse me.

First is the reserved word `const`, which I think I understand here. The first `const` refers to the `char*` which means that I cannot change the value of the pointer. The second `const` tells me that calling the function will not make changes to the state of the object I am calling. Is that a correct interpretation?

Second point of confusion is why one would have two methods with the same name and signature. How does the compiler know which one I meant to call? How do I know whether I am allowed to change the data after calling `data()` without know which of the two I called?

Comment: You're confusing `const char *` and `char * const`.

Comment: The trailing `const` is used in overload resolution. You need two because: What if you only have the first? You can't modify `data_`. What if you only have the second? You can't call it on a const object.

Comment: @KerrekSB  ouch.. I see I need to choose my words carefully in C++, and also the order in which I use them. I start liking this language already.

Comment: @DeltaLima, There are a lot of small details, tricks, and gotchas in C++. I found it pretty fun learning the little things bit by bit, most of them here on SO.

Comment: @chris Indeed lots of details and trick. It makes for a really powerful language with the low level capabilities that I missed in JAVA. I feel there is a long way ahead of me, but that's ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first function returns a pointer to constant data.  The `const` at the end of the function signature indicates that the function will not modify and class data members.

The second function returns a pointer to mutable data.  The caller can use the pointer to modify the class member variable.

Search the web and SO for "const correctness".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and search term "const correctness". A lot of good info to read into.

Comment: Also read through the "C++ FAQ" or "C++ FAQ lite".  It has helped me out a lot.

Comment: I agree with the very good description of the first function. For the second I would like to use: The second function return a pointer to mutable data, a call to this function can change the internal state of the object. The data returned is mutable but that doesn't imply that it must be member of the class. An interesting note for the first function is: the first method could not be static as the const modifier applied to the function prototipe has no meaning for class static function (as it is not binded with a class instance, no members are related to it, hence const has no meaning)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to declare const within a variable with a pointer:

```
const char *  // you can modify the pointer, not the item pointed to
char const *  // you can modify the pointer, not the item pointed to

char * const  // you can modify the item pointed to, not the pointer

const char const *  // you cannot modify either
char const * const  // you cannot modify either
const char * const  // you cannot modify either
```

As for the question, these two method definitions are overloads, and which one is called depends on the context.  For example, if the caller is also in a `const` method, and making the call on one of it's members (who is an instantiation of the class that has the `data()` methods), then the `const char * data() const` method will be called, and caller can only save the return value in a variable of type `const char *`.  Here is an example:

```
class MyClass {
  DataClass data_obj_;   // has both 'data()' methods described in your question
...
  void my_method () const {  // within this const method, data_obj_ cannot be modified
    const char * data = data_obj_.data();  // calls const method
...
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, your post was contradicting the others a bit in the beginning, but after some edits this makes a nice valuable post.

Comment: @DeltaLima - thanks!  I mis-read your question, originally, and I've been asked this a few times now and always have to look up the info.

Comment: @Tom "const char const *" --- what the heck is this? this is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where you would need both.

```
class foo {
    char* data_;
public:
    const char* data() const
    {
        return data_;
    }

    char* data()
    {
        return data_;
    }
};

const foo bar;
foo bar2;
bar->data();  // this uses the const version.
bar2->data(); // this uses the non-const version.
```

Because `bar` is a `const` object it would be an error to call `data()` non-const version.